# Como imprimir os prefixos junto com o array?

Tags: angularjs, array

Gostaria de uma ajuda para imprimir um array com seus prefixos.

```
this.prefixo = [
        {
            "E01":[{"name":"Teste01"}],
            "E02":[{"name":"Teste02"}]
        }
    ];
```

Eu gostaria de imprimir os prefixos e os nomes relacionados a cada prefixo.

Comment: Mas você pode ter mais de um nome por prefixo? Parece que tem arrays a mais nesse seu código, poderia ser um simples objeto.

Comment: No caso ele é uma lista de prefixo E0.... onde existe dados dentro de cada E0.... desse. Eu preciso no html selecionar esse prefixo onde através do prefixo que eu selecionar ele vai habilitar ou não alguns campos.

Comment: Imprimir? Em uma folha? Na tela em um alert? Passar o view model para uma tabela em html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, isso aí que você tem é um array com um objeto dentro: `[ { } ]`. Não tem mais nada nesse array, mas vou supor que pode ter outros objetos com o mesmo esquema. E esse objeto tem chaves (como `E01`) que apontam para outros arrays, cada uma com um outro objeto dentro, que tem o nome e o valor. Você vai precisar usar laços/loops aninhados para pegar tudo isso:

```js
this.prefixo = [
        {
            "E01":[{"name":"Teste01"}],
            "E02":[{"name":"Teste02"}]
        }
    ];


// Variáveis para organizar o código
var i, j, chave, objetoExterno, objetoInterno, arrayInterna

// Para cada item na array mais externa
for(i=0; i<this.prefixo.length; i++) {
  

  // o objetoExterno é o que contém as chaves;
  // no exemplo só tem 1, mas como é um array deles,
  // pode haver mais
  objetoExterno = this.prefixo[i];
  
  
  // Vamos ver quais são as chaves desse objeto
  // e o que elas contêm
  for(chave in objetoExterno) {
    
    // Cada chave do objeto contém uma array
    arrayInterna = objetoExterno[chave];
    
    // Pode haver vários itens dentro de cada array
    for(j=0; j<arrayInterna.length; j++) {
        
      
      // Cada item dessa array é um objeto que contém um nome
      objetoInterno = arrayInterna[j];
      
      imprime('Encontrado o nome ' + objetoInterno.name + ' na chave ' + chave);
      
    }
    
  }
  
}


// Imprime na janela de "resultado" do exemplo
function imprime(txt) {  
  document.body.innerHTML += txt + '<br>'; 
}
```

Com esses seus dados, os arrays são desnecessários. Se os dados fossem assim:

```
this.prefixo = {
  "E01":"Teste01",
  "E02":"Teste02"
};
```

Você poderia acessar facilmente cada nome pelo prefixo:

```
alert(this.prefixo.E01);
```